# How can I display different array values in react without getting map undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the original data:

```
const myArray = [
  'id': 'stuff', 'location': 'stuff2', 
  'phone_numbers'['stuff3','stuff4'], "address" : 'stuff5'
]


// so far, I'm getting the correct values back in an array from an API.
console.log(myReturnedArray) = [
{
"id": "10001",
"brand": "Best Brand",
"center_name": "Best Brand Texas",
"status": "Active",
"emails": [
  {
    "CreateDate": "October 12, 2022 at 10:59:09 AM UTC-5",
    "emailAddress": "test@test.com",
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "Tester",
    "id": "0eac8839-6e61-42f5-b55f-e2fa17b0262b",
    "licenseType": "Unlimited",
    "updateDate": "October 12, 2022 at 10:59:09 AM UTC-5",
    "userType": "STORE"
  }
],
"licenses": [
  {
    "CreateDate": "October 12, 2022 at 10:59:09 AM UTC-5",
    "licenseType": "STORE",
    "status": "ASSIGNED",
    "updatedBy": "SYSTEM",
    "updateDate": "October 12, 2022 at 10:59:09 AM UTC-5",
    "renewDate": "October 12, 2022 at 10:59:09 AM UTC-5",
    "expirationDate": "October 12, 2022 at 10:59:09 AM UTC-5",
    "id": "0eac8839-6e61-42f5-b55f-e2fa17b0262b"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

*** whenever i try a map function i get the error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, brand, center_name, status, emails, licenses}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." ***

I would like to display each value from my returned array in a `div` or `span`, but I keep getting errors like cannot get properties of undefined reading map, or a unique keys error whenever I try something.

```
// I would like to have each value from the object inside of myReturnedArray to use in my return statement.
return (
    <span>your email is : "test@test.com", </span>
    <div> your first name is : "Test" </div>
    <span> your last name is : "lastName": "Tester", </span>
);
```

Anytime I try and use a map function like this in my return statement:

```
{ myReturnedArray.map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>) }
```

It returns `myReturnedArray is undefined`. But when I do:

```
{ JSON.stringify(myReturnedArray) }
```

It renders `returnedArray` as a string correctly. So I know the return method has access to the array; I just can't display it.

Comment: Can you show us more react codes before the return statement?

Comment: `myArray` looks pretty messed up. Are you *sure* that is the correct format that is being returned by your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a name property in your array items.
Here is an example of code with your data that displays its content properly:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-euclid-nzbcp0?file=/src/App.js:24-283

Comment: This looks great, I tried your code with my actual data, i got the error that I listed in my question though. Could you try doing it with my actual data. I listed it in the question

Comment: If you mean this data 
const myArray = [
  'id': 'stuff', 'location': 'stuff2', 
  'phone_numbers'['stuff3','stuff4'], "address" : 'stuff5'
]
you have a problem, it's not an array, should be an object and you are missing a ":" between your 'phone_numbers' key and its value ['stuff3','stuff4']. 
That's probably why you got an error. I modified the code with that assumption and it works, check it out again and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

##### Final solution: [codeSandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s4qekd?file=src%2FApp.js)

###### Explantion to the errors you got:

**1:** The data structure you updated is very complex and nested with object inside array and arrays inside this object and so on. So, of course it will throw an error *"Objects are not valid as a React child"*.

You can't put an **entire** object between `div` tags, You need to map this object fields one by one to have single values between each `div`.

**2:** About the *"unique key"* issue - this is a **warning**, not an error. It's always showing this warning when you map object items to elements without adding the *`key`* attribute to each item.

So in order to get rid of this warning,  Just add the `key` attribute to the `div`s that are returned inside a `map` function, and choose some uniqe key.

---

### How can you map it like this?

As I understood, The structure you have is one big array - `myReturnedArray`, and in this array you will have many(*now you have just one*) **objects** when each one contains:

- An `emails` **array** which contains object(s).
- An `licenes` **array** which contains object(s).
- Some other *`key:value`* pairs.

In order to map `myReturnedArray` correctly - You'll need a `ForEach` loop that will map every *big* object inside of it, and then return all the mapped objects together.

---

First, I created an helper function that maps an array of objects(**without nested arrays or something**) to HTML `div` tags.

And I will use this function in order to map the `emails` and `licenes` arrays.

##### Helper function:

```
  const mapArrayOfObjects = (array) => {
    const arrayAsDivs = array.map((obj, index) => {
      const mappedObj = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
        return <div key={key}>{key + ' : ' + value}</div>;
      });
      return (
        //Returns a div with one object of the array and space after it.
        <div key={'nestedObj' + index}>
          {mappedObj}
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    });
    return arrayAsDivs; //The function returns ALL the mapped objects in the array.
  };
```

It looks complex, but all it does is going through the array, and mapping each object to a big `div` tag with all the *`key:value`* pairs as nested divs. (And I added the `br` to have some space between the objects. (*In your case you have just one object in the `emails`, but I assume that there would more.*)

##### Using `forEach`

In this function, I map all the *big* objects that are inside `myReturnedArray`:

```
const allObjectsHTML = [];

  myReturnedArray.forEach((obj) => {
    const emailsAsDivs = mapArrayOfObjects(obj.emails);
    const licensesAsDivs = mapArrayOfObjects(obj.licenses);
    const otherFields = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
      if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
        return <div key={key}>{key + " : " + value}</div>;
      }
    });
    const objectAsHTML = (
      <div>
        <div>{otherFields}</div>
        <div>
          <h3>Emails:</h3>
          {emailsAsDivs}
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Licenses:</h3>
          {licensesAsDivs}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    allObjectsHTML.push(objectAsHTML);
  });
```

**What this function does in each iteration:**

- Use the *helper function* to map the `emails`,`licenses` arrays.
- Map the rest of the *`key:value`* pairs in the object.
- Push the mapped object to the `allObjectsHTML` array that will contain **all** the mapped objects.

##### And for the last step

Now all you need to do is that in your JSX code you return:

```
 return (
    <>
      {allObjectsHTML.map((obj,index) => (
        <div key={"bigObj"+index}>{obj}<hr/></div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

This returns a mapped version of the `allObjectsHTML`.

##### This is the [codeSandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s4qekd?file=src%2FApp.js) of my code.

###### And in case you want to check if it works on many objects in your array:  [second codeSandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zonzir?file=src%2FApp.js).

**Note:** If you know for sure that you have **just one** object in the `myReturnedArray` - then you don't need to use `forEach`. See this [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vjqxhy?file=src%2FApp.js).

Answer (score 0):

The initial format of your data is flawed, it's not a JS syntax. To get it done properly first you have to make it a proper data container. For this kind of task you don't need arrays, you have an object for that.

```
  const data = {
    id: 'stuff',
    location: 'stuff2', 
    address: 'stuff5',
    phone_numbers: ['stuff3','stuff4']
  }
```

Then in your React Components return section you may ve it done like this:

```
const {id, location:dataLoc, address, phone_numbers:phNums} = data
const [num1, num2] = phNums

return (
    <div>{dataLoc}</div>
    <span>{address}</span>
    //etc
)
```

I also reformatted yopur code a bit to meet the JS naming conventions. We use camelCase here, so no phone_numbers (snake_case is for Py)but phNum.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think this question needed more specificity so I added my actual data. I still get the error though about objects not being valid with react child